# Returning one item from a tuple using recursion

Tags: python, recursion

```
def minmaxsum(lst):
    if len(lst) == 1:
        return lst[0], lst[0], lst[0]+lst[0]
    else:
        min_val, max_val, total = minmaxsum(lst[1:])
        if lst[0] < min_val:
            min_val = lst[0]
        if lst[0] > max_val:
            max_val = lst[0]
        total = min_val+max_val
        return min_val, max_val, total
```

Above I have my function that returns the minimum value, maximum value and sum of the minimum and maximum of a list.

I was wondering how I would go about altering the function to return solely the total, and not the mininum or maximum.

For example, for `a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]`,  `sum(a)` would return 7.

Comment: you shouldn't call your function `sum()` as that is a built-in

Comment: `sum_max_min = lambda lst: max(lst) + min(lst)`?

Comment: Where is the recursion? Is the function supposed to be called `sum_max_min`?

Comment: when i do that it returns int object is not iterable

Comment: sorry i want the function to return the sum of the max and min of the list

Comment: I have it working atm using a tuple but i only want to return the total

Comment: pass min/max as arguments, return only the total at the end

Comment: what is the expected output for an input of length `1` ?

Comment: just going to put in a req that the lists will always have atleast one element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If trying to avoid using built ins and definitely trying to do it recursively, I'd personally do something like this which is along the lines of your original logic:

```
def min_max_sum(in_list, min=None, max=None):
    if len(in_list) == 0:
        return min+max
    if min is None and max is None:
        min = in_list[0]
        max = in_list[0]
    if in_list[0] < min:
        min = in_list[0]
    if in_list[0] > max:
        max = in_list[0]
    return min_max_sum(in_list[1:], min=min, max=max)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just pass those values as arguments, and only return the total, something like:

```
In [3]: def minmaxsum(lst, _min=float('inf'), _max=float('-inf')):
   ...:     if not lst:
   ...:         return _min + _max
   ...:     else:
   ...:         head, *rest = lst
   ...:         return minmaxsum(rest, min(_min, head), max(_max, head))
   ...:

In [4]: minmaxsum([1,2,3,4,5,6])
Out[4]: 7
```

If you want to keep your `minmaxsum` signature to only accept a list, use a helper function:

```
In [8]: def _minmaxsum_helper(lst, _min=float('inf'), _max=float('-inf')):
   ...:     if not lst:
   ...:         return _min + _max
   ...:     else:
   ...:         head, *rest = lst
   ...:         _min = min(_min, head)
   ...:         _max = max(_max, head)
   ...:         return _minmaxsum_helper(rest, _min, _max)
   ...:

In [9]: def minmaxsum(lst):
   ...:     return _minmaxsum_helper(lst)
   ...:

In [10]: minmaxsum([1,2,3,4,5,6])
Out[10]: 7
```

Comment: my functions only passing in the list

Comment: @Kevin ok, *then use a helper function*.

Answer (score 0):

The logic of your function is sound, you just need to handle the base case when the function is called so that you return the total rather than a tuple of `(min, max, total)`. This can be achieved through the use of a helper function, or through the use of an optional parameter.

Below, I have implemented the use of an optional parameter (`mm`) which signals whether to return the `(min, max)` tuple (with no total). So by default, this is `False`, but when calling the function recursively, we set this to `True`.

```
def sum_min_max(lst, mm=False):
    if len(lst) == 1:
        if mm:
            return lst[0], lst[0]
        else:
            return lst[0] + lst[0]
    else:
        min_val, max_val = sum_min_max(lst[1:], True)
        if lst[0] < min_val:
            min_val = lst[0]
        if lst[0] > max_val:
            max_val = lst[0]
        if mm:
            return min_val, max_val
        else:
            return min_val + max_val
```

and some tests:

```
>>> sum_min_max([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
7
>>> sum_min_max([5, 2, 1, 3, 4, 2])
6
```

---

Although personally I would use the above, here is the helper function solution that achieves the same effect (in more lines):

```
def _min_max_rec(l):
    if len(l) == 1:
        return l[0], l[0]
    else:
        min_val, max_val = _min_max_rec(l[1:])
        if l[0] < min_val:
            min_val = l[0]
        if l[0] > max_val:
            max_val = l[0]
        return min_val, max_val

def sum_min_max(lst):        
    r = _min_max_rec(lst)
    return r[0] + r[1]
```

Comment: sorry my base case would return the total of lst[0]+lst[0]

Comment: @Kevin Ah, I see what you mean, by "base case", you are referencing the case where `len(lst) == 1`. I have fixed this now :)

Comment: @JoeIddon generally, I would put the helper-function definition outside the main function, unless you are using a closure to maintain state or something like that.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Okay that's an idea but obviously either way works here. Personally, I prefer it this way as to not clutter up the name space :)

Comment: Yeah, but now you are re-defining the function each time you call the main function. Just pre-pend an underscore and the module namespace will be just fine...

Comment: Will do in a bit!

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I have just done so, nice trick thank you :)